# setState not working for objects inside the this.state in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, react-component

I am working with forms in React and facing this weird issue.

This is how my component class looks -

```js
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: 'Bla'
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <label> Name: <input type="text" value={this.state.username} name="username" /> </label>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

And this is how the rendered page looks in the browser.

[image]

I am able to update/change the text in the textbox.

Now I tweak my component class a bit, basically I change the `this.state` object and correspondingly update the HTML input element.

These are the changes done-

```js
this.state = {
   formEle: {
      username: 'Bla'
   }
};
```

```html
<label> Name: <input type="text" value={this.state.formEle.username} name="username" /> </label>
```

After making these two changes when I render the page in my browser everything is same except I am not able to update/change the content in the textbox.

My hunch is there must be some issue with the `this.setState` function, but when I printing the values of `event.target.name` and `event.target.value` I am getting the expected value. Not sure what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're no longer able to update your input box is that you're no longer setting the correct state variable.

If you change your `handleChange` event listener to look like this, stuff should start working again:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ 
    formEle: {
      ...this.state.formEle,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    },
  });
}
```

You specified that you want to read state from this.state.formEle.username, so therefore you need to make sure you're setting that particular part of the state tree.

Hope this helps - and happy coding!